# Java - current executed app path

Tags: java

I would like to get current app path in the app.

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current config file path is: " + s);
```

It seems working well, BUT when I use like below.

```
> pwd
> /usr/local/
> java -jar app/getapppath.jar // executed app inside app folder
> Current config file path is : /usr/local // I want /usr/local/app
```

I can executed my app after 'cd app', but I want to fix it fundamentally. Any idea of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use classloader to get that information. Here is a example, which you can adopt to your needs:

```
package test;
import java.net.URL;

public class a { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL u = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test/a.class");
    System.out.println(u);
  }
}
```

In my case it works as:

```
 $ cd /tmp
 $ java -cp /home/me a
 file:/home/me/a.class
 $
```

Comment: I have config file outside of app, and try to read this config file from app. both are same path/folder. Is your answer able to do this?

Comment: well, current working path is available as Paths.get(""), is n your example. If you want to get path to the jar/class files, then you can use my example.